# Rails: Return JSON of Stripe Response from Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, stripe-payments

I have multiple clients relying on my server that processes Stripe charge requests. When a charge is processed, I want to send my client back JSON of whether the charge was successfully created, and if it wasn't, the reasons why.

My server can be viewed [here](https://murmuring-wave-13313.herokuapp.com/charges/new).

The code for my controller is the following:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

      #*WHAT I TRIED DOING THAT DIDN'T WORK*
      # respond_to do |format|
      #   msg = { :status => "ok", :message => "Success!"}
      #   format.json  { render :json => msg }
      # end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end
```

I am trying to call my RESTful API with the following URL:

```
curl -XPOST https://murmuring-wave-13313.herokuapp.com/charges.json?stripeToken=tok_*****************&stripeEmail=rsheeler@gmail.com
```

I'm assuming I need to access some of the [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#metadata), but I'm unsure how to.

Which results in a `500 Response`

How can I properly structure my Charges controller in order to return JSON of Stripe's response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm smacking myself. What I realized was after you make the `Stripe::Charge` object, a JSON-serialized `Charge` object is assigned to it.

Because of this, you can access all the metadata in the `Charge` instance by simply calling `charge.attribute_name`. For instance, if it was a valid charge, `charge.status` would return "succeeded". Because what assigned back to charge is JSON you can simply return `render charge` if the requested format is JSON.

The working Charge controller looks like the following:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

      # If in test mode, you can stick this here to inspect `charge` 
      # as long as you've imported byebug in your Gemfile
      byebug

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json  { render :json => charge }
        format.html  { render :template => "charges/create"}
      end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesnt this work?

```
#*WHAT I TRIED DOING THAT DIDN'T WORK*
 respond_to do |format|
   msg = { :status => "ok", :message => "Success!"}
   format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
   format.html  { render :template => "charges/create"}
 end
```

What are the errors in your log?

Comment: I realized I royally screwed up and forgot to commit `format.html  { render :template => "charges/create"}` within this condition to heroku, so the errors i was getting wouldn't be pertinent to my original question (i don't think at least). sorry for any confusion.