# JSON missing a template for this request format and variant coming from React using Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, request, format

i am working on an online store in React with backend in Rails and i use Stripe. After i send the fetch request towards my charges controller gets sent successfully, i can see the parameters , everything good.

```
Started POST "/charges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-10 20:22:16 +0000
Processing by ChargesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"description"=>"Only the Book", "source"=>"tok_1Bu4rRHmkRoa1PQ1R3ndnG2o", "amount"=>100, "charge"=>{"description"=>"Only the Book", "source"=>"tok_1Bu4rRHmkRoa1PQ1R3ndnG2o", "amount"=>100}}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/charges/new
Completed 302 Found in 2554ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But when the controller create action performs the redirection towards the new method, i get this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ChargesController#new is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []):
```

I tried renspond_to :json in the controller in the new method, does not work, i tried to deserialize the params passing them to instance variables but they wont work because they are nil, i did not try json builder yet because i do not know if this would be the simpler way.
This is my code below:
charges_controller.rb
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

```
  def new
   @amount = params[:stripeAmount]
   @description = params[:stripeDescription]
  end

  def create

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => params[:stripeAmount],
      :description => params[:stripeDescription],
      :currency    => 'GBP'
    )  
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
end
```

this is my new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: <%= (@amount) %></span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="<%= @description %>"
          data-amount="<%= @amount %>"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

Thank you very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your not responding with json. Your rescue is a html response, so that will definitely not work. You need to send the response back as json since that's what your react app expects. It's been a while since I've used stripe, but something like this:

The following would assume you have `respond_with`:

```
respond_to :json

def create
  # ... your stripe customer and charge api requests
  respond_with charge
end
```

Or if you don't have `respond_with`:

```
def create
  # ... your stripe customer and charge 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: charge }
  end
end
```

This is the similar problem: [Rails: Return JSON of Stripe Response from Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985521/rails-return-json-of-stripe-response-from-server)

Comment: many thanks for your fast help i used the second approach but i put it in my "new" method as well since i need those variables to fill in the info in the form is this correct way to do it ? Now it works i get a 200 on charges/new but the actual payment is not being made in the stripe API. If you have any other suggestion that would be highly appreciated Thank you so much

Comment: What response do you get when you run the `Stripe::Charge.create` from the rails console or if you debug the `charge` object after? Would also need to know if your just testing still, or trying to run this in production. I believe stripe has "test mode" and "live mode". In any case that would be a separate question for you to ask or search on SOF.

Comment: many thanks i figured it out eventually i wasn't passing the correct params on stripe so the charge object was not getting created at all now it all works many thanks for your help :)